What separates numbers from other mathematical objects and what justifies e.g. the quaternions to be called a number system?
In mathematics, what we mean by a number changes as one advances one's mathematical education. At first, numbers are used to count, enumerate, etc. Then we keep extending our number systems to allow us to solve progressively more complex equations which historically was probably what allowed us to call these quantities "numbers". For instance, the integers allow us to solve equations that require us to subtract quantities, the rationals allow us to solve equations that require us to divide quantities, the reals and complex numbers allow us to solve polynomial equations more generally.
But why would one consider something like the quaternions, octonions, or even the modular arithmetic rings to be "numbers"? After all, from the fundamental theorem of algebra we know that there is no need for a bigger field than the complex numbers to solve all our polynomial equations, so I have trouble understanding why we would call something like the quaternions a number system. What exactly separates numbers from other mathematical objects? Is it purely cultural or historical or is there something more? After all, real numbers are usually defined either as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, or as Dedekind cuts, and neither of these particularly look like a number to me.

See e.g. Friedrich Waismann, Introduction to Mathematical Thinking and see Wittgenstein's Family resemblance.

It's just convention. If you can add and subtract it and multiply and divide it, then you can probably call it a number without too many raised eyebrows.

So any element of any field is a number according to this? Then why don't we call any elements of any field numbers?

On a case by case basis, if the author feels like calling it that, especially if it's used in a similar context to other things called numbers.

See also Richard Samuels & Eric Snyder, Number Concepts: An Interdisciplinary Inquiry (Cambridge University Press, 2024)

Also it doesn't always have to be a field - consider the cardinal numbers, which do not form a field.

@causative Abstract algebra applies to a range of ontological primitives. For instance, one can have a group with transformations of a triangle on a plane. Those shapes are not considered numbers. Rather the notion of group, ring, and field show that there can be an isomorphism between numbers and other non-number abstractions; there is no claim that having the same abstract algebraic structure makes those non-number abstractions numbers themselves. Only that there is an abstraction available to describe them.

Are the hyperreals *R numbers? (some have argued that *R^3 is a better model of physical space than R^3). Surely the answer can’t be a matter for physics to decide. But then we have to accept any dense linear order as a set of “numbers” (even those with huge cardinality, like supercompacts)? I bet many would reject that idea. I doubt you’d ever get anything like a consensus on what counts as a “number.” And just as importantly, it’s hard to see why it matters. It’s just an arbitrary label.

define 'chair'. definitions are hard.

Quaternions can follow arithmetic operations with regular numbers.

ἐν τῷ ἀριθμῷ δέ τε τὰ παντ' ἐπέοικε

@KennethKho "Quaternions can follow arithmetic operations with regular numbers."  -  you may be interested in the Frobenius Theorem

Y'know how when people say "there's no such thing as a fish", by which they mean that as biologists have learned more about how different types of animals are and aren't related, there hasn't arisen a good definition for the category of "fish".*
So while they may use the term colloquially, or as part of a technical term, e.g. "bony fishes", most biology proceeds without bothering to debate whether this or that animal is actually a "fish".
Well, it's basically the same with mathematicians and "number". I've gotten as far as a master's in math, and I don't think I've spent as much as two minutes total discussing what is or isn't a number. I will gladly use the term "complex number", but that's just a name that could be replaced if it wasn't for the convenience of tradition. As others have indicated, we spend our time discussing what operations we can perform on mathematical objects, and what rules those operations follow.
One can ask "okay, which objects do get called numbers?", but the answer is going to include a large dose of history and the traditions of human (mathematical) culture - you will not end up with a single agreed, consistent set of rules.

* Because comments are considered temporary, and are sometimes just deleted, I thought I'd incorporate Ilmari Karonen's excellent comment into this answer:
Regarding the fish example specifically, biologists like their taxonomic categories to be monophyletic, i.e. containing all species descending from a single common ancestor. But there is no monophyletic group that contains e.g. both sharks and tuna and doesn't also contain all land vertebrates including humans. So if we try to define a monophyletic category of "fish", then either sharks aren't fish, tuna aren't fish or humans are fish

+1 Generally attributed to Stephen J. Gould, specifically: https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/11p7ln/til_stephen_jay_gould_discovered_that_all/

Regarding the fish example specifically, biologists like their taxonomic categories to be monophyletic, i.e. containing all species descending from a single common ancestor. But there is no monophyletic group that contains e.g. both sharks and tuna and doesn't also contain all land vertebrates including humans. So if we try to define a monophyletic category of "fish", then either sharks aren't fish, tuna aren't fish or humans are fish.

I think this is probably the closest I will get to an actual answer, the fish analogy is very effective, thank you!

@JD It's not an idea that originates with Gould or deserves to be credited to him, although he certainly spread it more widely.

And indeed very often we put up with terrible terminology like 'imaginary number', because though it may mislead laypeople what is being referenced in math is clear. I agree with this answer, but as with fish a little more classifying can be usefully done than this, rather than just dismissing the category.

If you like this answer, you might like an idea that bears on definitions: family resemblance.

Another useful term to consider would be "field."  Unlike "number," "field" is rigorously defined, and you can show that the only fields over ℝⁿ are the reals, complex numbers, quaternions, octonions, and the sedions, so they are special in that sense. (Or, more rigorously, they are all isomorphic to one of those)

@IlmariKaronen "So if we try to define a monophyletic category of "fish", then either sharks aren't fish, tuna aren't fish or humans are fish." ... Well, you know The California Third District Court of Appeal ruled that bees can be legally classified as "fish" under the California Endangered Species Act (CESA)...

@IlmariKaronen: I think that’s part of why the parallel with “numbers” fits well.  There’s no reasonable monophyletic definition of “fish”, so it’s not received any established technical definition — but that keeps it free for more flexible use as a non-technical term.  Similarly with “numbers”.  It’s important to have good technical terminology, well domesticated with precise definitions — but it’s useful to keep a few concepts around in their wild state too.

@BenHocking It's more that they ruled that CESA's specific definition of "fish" was broad enough to include bees, because it's honestly a pretty bad definition for anything but legal purposes in that specific act: "“Fish” means a wild fish, mollusk, crustacean, invertebrate, amphibian, or part, spawn, or ovum of any of those animals."

@Idran Yeah, which is pretty much what I said, though I admit I left out the additional context. While their ruling is funny, it's not ridiculous when you understand that additional context, which is presumably your point.

@BenHocking Ah yeah, sorry, I should've made that clearer.

@CortAmmon Out of the sets you wrote, only the reals and the complex numbers form a field

@user49822 THank you for catching that glaring error on my part.  I got my words mixed up.  The thing I should have done is pull up wikipedia and quote it directly.  Then I would have named the right concept: "the reals, complex numbers, quaternions, and octonions are the only (normed) division algebras (over the real numbers). "  That's the property I was supposed to be claiming!

For instance a+ib is a number but [[a b][-b a]] is not.

The real numbers have been around since Simon Stevin already in the 16th century.  He pioneered the viewpoint of specifying a number by its unending decimal expansion (though his notation for it was cumbersome and is not used today).
As late as the 19th century there was still hesitation whether to refer to negatives and numbers.  For instance, Cauchy still treats them as entities in their own right.  Infinitesimals were variously referred to as numbers, magnitudes, or quantities by Leibniz, Euler, and Cauchy.
As to which systems should be considered "numbers", the answer depends significantly on the philosophical position of the speaker.  Platonists would tend to respond that the buck stops at the real or complex numbers (it would be almost impossible to fight the latter given their usefulness).
Meanwhile, the body of your question already contains the germs of an answer from the position of mathematical Formalism: we successively extend the number system due to the usefulness of the extended system.  Thus, we add infinitesimals to our repertoire of numbers because we want to do mathematical analysis and analyze change and areas.
Similar remarks apply to the Hamilton quaternions: this number system, in addition to being on the short list of very special algebras (include also the octonions), are often useful in such fields as computer vision (you probably wouldn't catch computer scientists using matrices in this context, even though it could be done).

Thank you, this is very insightful. Would the idea that "anything that can be added, subtracted, multiplied or divided is a number" fall into mathematical formalism as well?

In algebra they study a class of objects called quaternion algebras (in fact I have a couple of publications closely related to these).  These are generalisations of the algebra of the Hamilton quaternions, but I think it would be far-fetched to refer to their elements as numbers; in practice few people do.  So I would guess that it is not enough to be able to perform arithmetic operations.

I am asking this, because we do call elements of various algebras (the sedenions come to mind) "hypercomplex numbers". But maybe this is more so due to abstraction and generalization from the complex numbers instead, and the term stuck around due to this.

You have a (wait for it) number of questions. Let's see.
First, you ask:

But why would one consider something like the quaternions, octonions or even the modular arithmetic rings to be "numbers"?

The you ask:

What exactly separates numbers from other mathematical objects?

Lastly you ask:

Is it purely cultural or historical or is there something more?

Let's see what we can do.
First, in philosophy of mathematics, there are realist and anti-realist positions, and example of the former is Platonism and of the latter might intuitionism (SEP). So, before even addressing questions, it's important to observe that people have different fundamental frameworks in how they approach the world. These are, of course, metaphysical presuppositions we all bring to the table in our discourse. And yet, not all mathematicians reflect on these ideas, and some simply do math for the sake of doing mathematics.
But many who do mathematics are motivated by applications to other problems, and they stretch concepts and definitions to suit those ends. For instance, if one were to consider a Newton's fluxion a number and suitable for calculations, one suddenly could find instantaneous rates of change. Of course, Berkeley famously objected. This is not different over the rows such as 'Is 0 a number?' and 'Is i a number?'. In every case, by introducing a new class of numbers, an entire branch of mathematics seems to follow. Thus, quarternions were an attempt to model space mathematically, which, if one pays attention to history, is a rather profitable intellectual venture. Einstein used Minkowski's model and viola! Now we have GPS.
The second question is tougher to answer because there is a lack of consensus, but according to some, Kroencker famously claimed:

“Die ganzen Zahlen hat der liebe Gott gemacht, alles andere ist Menschenwerk”
(traditionally rendered: “God made natural numbers; all else is the work of man“.)

Here then is a suggestion that numbers are a somewhat arbitrary notion of abstract object (SEP), and it is philosophically contentious to argue any definition of number. Again, a realist has to appeal to some sort of evidence that "true" numbers have some sort of mind independent existence, and anti-realists see numbers as some type of construction. Here the philosophy of mathematics really kicks into overdrive because different positions (the empirical, the structural, the neo-Platonic) all have different frameworks. Suffice it to say, mathematicians do seem to presume a general ontological commitment that numbers are an ontological commitment of primitives and are made sensible in sentences though the use of relations to compare them and operations to transform them. Intuitively, then numbers are the basic units that can change or involve claims regarding truth values relative to propositions which compose theories when they act as axioms/postulates and theorems/lemma/corollaries.
New numbers tend to just subsume previous numbers and the theories attached to them. Thus, someone doesn't just point to some squiggles and claim, new numbers! Rather, the counting numbers were extended to wholes and then integers and reals and so on. This is what Kroenecker meant in his quotation. That counting numbers are the prototype for all numbers and mathematicians have been steadily extending the definitions of how they are constructed (or discovering them if they are realists). When one understands the quarternion, for instance, one can apply abstract algebra and examine the structure in the light of identity, associativity, transitivity, commutativity, and so on.
So, are numbers cultural and historical? Yes. But there is a pragmatic and technical aspect to their development also. First, they have to be continuous with previous numbers and theories more or less. Second, they fill a particular ontological role in the formal systems of which they are a part. Third, they have to function as primitives in the language. Fourth, they have to be of some usefulness to theories whether pure or applied. So, there are definitely empirical and linguistic constraints on what serves as a number. And generally, they have to do with the topic that mathematical language deals with: quantity, order, direction, shape, and so on.
Ultimately, it might be best to think about the various currently accepted classes of numbers of extension of the notion of order. After all, a sequence is defined as a mapping of the naturals, and the naturals are defined in PA with the successor function. We can extend that with negative integers to make order infinite in two dimensions. The reals allow us to give intervals an infinite but ordered sequence between any tow numbers. Complex numbers extend infinity in four directions. Transfinite numbers allow us to order infinities themselves. But in every case (and my biases towards constructivism become evident), what is key is that numbers provide a series of methods for applying a sequence in constructing a class of useful abstract objects.

I will be a bit provocative here.
And say that any collection, that we define some operation that we call addition over.
Is a collection of numbers.
Matrices? - Numbers
Ordered Pairs? - Numbers
functions? - Numbers
Strings? - Numbers
Ordinals? - Numbers
So why do we call some things numbers, and others not?
It has to do with why we call some operations addition.
But in short, if we are adding two things... it makes sense to call them numbers.

I don't think people would call strings numbers though. What field of mathematics does that? Also I assume that by addition you mean concatenation, which isn't really addition in my opinion, though that is my own bias on the question.

You can associate an infinite sequence of natural numbers with a unique real number.  Addition of sequences, means you add consider a new sequence where the ith term is the sum of the ith terms of the oroginal sequences. The structure here, is isomorphic to the Real Number Line, with a similiar definition for multiplication. So, all the theorems about reals, hold for infinite sequences of natural numbers. So, the infinite sequences may as well be real numbers.  It's nonstandard to call a sequence a string, sorry about that.

Also, you can just consider concatenation as addition. It's fairly similar, conceptually to "adding" line segements, and it's not strange to think of numbers as lengths. The Ancient Greeks often thought of them that way.

@Saegusa "What field?" -- Computer Science, for one. I'm with the "At least a big portion of Computer Science is a subfield of math" crowd, and that's the very part that deals with strings too. But if you question yourself here, you might be interested in https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24386356 and https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/r6w2za/do_you_think_computer_science_a_branch_of/

@noncom You are missing my point, most computer scientists don't call strings numbers.

@Saegusa - What does it matter how some people call some things? The only thing that matters is that with what you call such and so you can do lots of interesting things that someone else might also find interesting. Bit strings definitely can be seen as (what I call) numbers, for instance. Any representation can be encoded as a binary string. So, there you go... Natural numbers can be defined as games (see Conway's book about surreal numbers)... So, reversely games are also numbers...

@Saegusa Yeah, can't really say what you meant then, so could have easily missed. In computer science strings are sequencies of bytes or chars (or Unicode points, God forbid), both of which are "kinds of numbers". In many applications it's only the length of the string that matters, but in data archivation, search, network transmission, various hashing algorithms, cryptography, vector databases, etc, etc, the nature of strings as numbers plays the most important role because it directly takes part in calculations. So saying "string" they mean "string data", which is numbers.

^^^ might be not what you meant, but just to give some context to my original response.

@mudskipper The question was specifically about things generally called number systems, if you want to call strings numbers you're obviously free to do it.

Imaginary numbers can usefully be thought of as describing rotations around an axis described by the real numbers.
Ring theory lets us understand how to think about discrete symmetry groups in general, like the rotations of objects with their own symmetries. Discrete symmetry groups are special cases of continuous symmetries under transformation, ie Lie groups. Noether's theorem tells us that conservation laws are exactly equivalent to, stating specific continuous symmetries. This leads to the general concept in physics of Gauge Theories.
I suggest it's obvious from this, that we can think of numberlines not as magically connecting us to a Platonic realm, but as intuitions that emerge from our intersubjective experience, of continuous symmetries. If we move an object in units along what seems relatively flat ground, in relatively flat spacetime, we can extend our experience of subitism into an intuition about the real numberline, to algorithmic ways to reach computationally tractable parts of it, and define operations for the interactions of numbers. Vectors are another intuitive thing to experience, with their own different operations eg ones that don't commute. Emergence of mathematics from intersubjectivive experiences discussed more here:
The Unreasonable Ineffectiveness of Mathematics in most sciences
In this picture, numberlines are abstractions from our experiences of continuous symmetries. In that sense there are only more and less general symmetry groups, with our intuitions shaped fundamentally but not only by spatial translations.

NB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Numbers are what you can use to count and to refer to quantitative qualities of something. You can't count and calculate with something that is not a number. It's enough to say "this is one, and this is another". And when you can, it's a number, and the number theory, with algebra, calculus, etc., follow.
To provide the ability, numbers must be a class of objects that allow existence of disinct values in a set of otherwise uniform objects. The specifics of how that distinction is provided, and consequentially what structure and interrelationships the numbers can have between themselves, defines the type of the number.
Also...
